# Get a specific part of style attribute in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

If I used `.GetAttribute("style")` and it returned:

> width:200px;height:300px;background-image:url('http://someurl.com/image.png");position:absolute;

How would I go about getting the background-image URL?

[ EDIT ]
I should also mention that the background-image changes every now and again, it doesn't stay the same.

[ EDIT ]  I am trying to pull the background image from bing in a webbrowser. I want to set the background as my form background.

[EDIT]

```
Try
            With bingCheck
                Dim bgDiv As HtmlElement = .Document.GetElementById("bgDiv")
                Dim imgUrl As String = bgDiv.Style("background-image").ToString

                Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(imgUrl), HttpWebRequest)
                Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse)
                Dim grabbedImage As Image = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream)
                response.Close()

                Me.BackgroundImage = grabbedImage
                Me.Update()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Comment: What type is providing the `GetAttribute` method?

Comment: Also, which control are do you need to get the style for?

Answer (score 0):

Many controls provide built-in Style collection. So you can do something like:

```
Dim sUrl As String = xMyControl.Style("background-image")
```

Comment: `Document.GetElementById` looks kind of strange in VB.NET - is this a code inside of WinForm app and not in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str = "width:200px;height:300px;background-image:url('http://someurl.com/image.png');position:absolute;"
Dim v = "background-image:url("
Dim i = str.IndexOf(v) + v.Length + 1
Dim j = str.IndexOf(")", i)
Dim url = str.Substring(i, j - i - 1)
```